# Using Firebase and Nuxt3 server routes error: "i.consume is not a function"?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxtjs3, nitro

I am trying to test out using Firebase with Nuxt3 server routes and for some reason get the following error:

**`[nitro] [dev] [unhandledRejection] TypeError: i.consume is not a function`**

I Googled and nothing came up, nor nothing here in stackoverflow question archive.

Anyone got any ideas what is causing the problem?

All I am trying to do is get all the posts from my firestore database like so using Nuxt3's server routes:

`server/api/posts/all.ts`:

```js
import { firestore } from '@/server/utils/firebase';

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const colRef = firestore.collection('posts').orderBy('createdAt', 'desc');
  const querySnapshot = await colRef.get();
  const posts = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    posts.push(doc.data());
  });
  return {
    posts,
  };
});
```

Then, I call it in `app.vue`:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    {{ data }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const { data } = await useFetch(`/api/posts/all`);

</script>
```

Nothing is shown on the UI except for a console error. Anyone got any ideas?

**I have a minimal reproduction link here that shows the error:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-j4ueey?file=app.vue**

Comment: Which exact package are you using? Did you checked it's issues, if somebody faced it before?

Comment: I am using the Firebase NodeJS SDK for the api routes: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#windows

Comment: heads up! Works in my VSCODE reproduction, but not on stackblitz sandbox....

Comment: So this is a problem with stackblitz as the same exact code works fine locally.

Comment: So, you don't have a problem with your code while working locally? I guess we can close this question haha.

Comment: Correct. I do have anothe rquestion that I will post shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, the issue is not happening locally only on Codesandbox.
So it's basically a non-issue!

Was probably something regarding the sandboxed environment itself.